# Extract group emails from group emails (groups in groups) apps script and then emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, admin, google-groups

I'm working on a script which consist in get members from a group, 
the script identifies if the mail whether is a group email or a member email,
but, in my job, we have groups in groups !

So here's the script

```
function getGroupUsers() {
var group = sheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group).members;
for (var i = 1; i < members.length; i++) {
  var member = members[i];
  var caseUser = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1);
  var caseGroupe = sheet.getRange(i+1, 2);   

  var lastRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 3);
//  var caseGroupe2 = sheet.getRange(i+1, 4);

switch (member.type) {
    case 'USER':
      Logger.log('%s is a user', member.email);
      caseUser.setValue(member.email);
      break;
    case 'GROUP':
      Logger.log('%s is a group', member.email);
      //var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(member.email);
      caseGroupe.setValue(member.email);
      break;
    default:
      Logger.log('nothing');
  }
```

That's workin, as groups going in the second column, but i need them to be auto extended , like what I'm doing with the loop in the begining, but I'm not sure how can it works, I tried loops in loops but when I get members of the group there's only one written in the case instead of all.

If you need more information, or you need me to explain a point you're not sure to understand just tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit. The thing that you mentioned about doing a loop inside a loop was correct.

I did something similar but instead of having a loop inside a loop, i created a new function, and then call it recursively. This was to handle the case where a group would have another group, and that other group would have another group as member.

```
function getGroup(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var group = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();  
  var subgroup = 1;
  getMembers(group, subgroup, cell, sheet);  
  cell.activate();  
}


function getMembers(group, subgroup, cell, sheet)
{
  var col =  cell.getColumn() +subgroup;
  var row =  cell.getRow() +1;
  try{  
    var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group).members;
    if(!members)
    {
      return 0; 
    }
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    return;
  }
  var offset = 0;
  for(var member in members){
    var newcell = sheet.getRange(row++,col);
    newcell.setValue(members[member].email);    
    if(members[member].type == 'GROUP'){
      newcell.activate();
      offset = getMembers(members[member].email,subgroup , sheet.getActiveCell() ,sheet);
      row = row + offset;
    }
  }
  return  member.length + offset;
}
```

I hope this helps in what you intended to do.

Comment: big thanks, that's working ! but it doesn't develop the whole group, i got TypeError: Can not read the property "length" from undefined about this line :     'return  member.length + offset;'  but the idea is here, that's work like i thought it would work !

Comment: I edited the code. I didn't test it for groups without members.

Comment: that's this case , it stops when groups have 0 members, i've tried some if and other conditions but it doen't matter

Comment: Do you still get the error even with the edited code I posted?

Comment: My bad! That's working ! All users from all groups are now on the sheet, thank you! no more error, now I'm trying to find a way to show members from all groups in the same column to make the sheet more "readable", if you have ideas you're welcome :)