# google apps scripting of group members doesn't match the webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to extract a list of emails from a google group I manage.  Its well above the 5k limit for a simple export so I tried to use a google apps script to do this.

Problem is, in the apps script the number of users returned is about 25% less than the webapp displays (14513 vs 18873).  Here is the app script

```
var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("groupemail@google.com");//not the real email
Logger.log("Group user count " + group.getUsers().length);
```

From some simple testing it also looks like the missing users are possibly the ones with the oldest registration dates (tested by pulling usernames to test at random and then sorted by registration date)

So has anyone run into this before or can you point me to another way to get the rest of the users?  Thanks.

EDIT:  From the api docs I noticed this

```
getUsers()   Retrieves the direct members of the group that have
             a known corresponding    Google account.
```

which explains the missing users, but not how to get the rest of the emails

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there are members in a group that are inside a group which were not included when running your query since [`getUsers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getUsers()) in Groups Service only retrieves all the direct members of the group.

Please try using the advanced [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) in retrieving group members in a domain. With this service, you may then use [Members: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) to be able to get members that are inside or outside of your account's domains.

To help you with the implementation of this service, please check suggested solutions in these SO posts - [Extract group emails from group emails (groups in groups) apps script and then emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883992/extract-group-emails-from-group-emails-groups-in-groups-apps-script-and-then-e) and [Using Directory API in Google-Apps-Script, how to get groups inside a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455649/using-directory-api-in-google-apps-script-how-to-get-groups-inside-a-group).